# Group of Order 30 with 15 sylow 2 subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a group $G$ of order $30$, with $15$ Sylow-2 subgroups. Then how do I show that $G \cong D_{15}$. I know we can consider a semi-direct product $G = \mathbb{Z}_{15} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and get $\mathbb{Z}_{30}, D_{15}, \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times S_{3}, \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times D_{5}$. But I am not sure how to use the fact that there are $15$ Sylow-2 subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Only one of those groups has 15 different order-2 subgroups (which is to say 15 distinct order-2 elements). That's rather easily checked.

Comment: So is it sufficient to say that by inspection $D_{15}$ has 15 elements of order $2$, which are $\tau \sigma ^n , n \in [15]$ and therefore is the only possible group of order 30 with that property? Or would there need to be further justification?

Comment: @user100101212 If you're confident that you have found all possible groups of order $30$, then yes, pointing out that $D_{15}$ has the required number of Sylow-2 subgroups while none of the others do will be enough.